# Java - Read cookie after a post

Tags: java, post, cookies

I'm having trouble reading what cookies are being sent when making a POST in java.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String urlParameters = "votebut=";
    String request = "http://www.runelocus.com/toplist/vote-17648.html";
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
    for (String cookie : cookies) {
        System.out.println("Cookies: " + cookie);
    }
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

This is what it prints:
`Cookies: PHPSESSID=48863f8c3adcbddf0e77e7f1b450fc0e; path=/`

This is what I want it to print:
`ki_u=68debd85-c1af-f1ff-2e6c-4146755c6e26; ki_t=1354418220596%3B1354418220596%3B1354422379616%3B1%3B36;`

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you setting the expected cookies?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to read that cookies in that way.

In response to `http://www.rune...17648.html` you only get `PHPSESSID` cookie in response headers.

That cookies which you are looking for (`ki_u` and `ki_t`) are set by JavaScript code in this file:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/ki.js/45645/919.js
```

So to actually get that cookies values you need to replicate browser behavior or actually use a browser (to request the html page, parse it, download referred resources (particularly `919.js`) and execute JavaScript code).

Comment: Can you please show me a way to do it? I'm not so good at html. Maybe a code or something?

Comment: @user1869674 I can't think of how you could do that programmatically using Java. I would use a browser and an integrated tool for automation (e.g. Selenium) to do such task.